# is it possible to communicate over webservices in web2py application?

Tags: python, web-services, python-3.x, web2py

I have to develop one web2py application which will run on one machine (lets say SERVER), this machine will have MySql database also installed and running.
Users can connect remotely to the Web2py app over Https(Lets say it CLIENT)
There is one more system running over the network(Lets say N/W Panel) which can send the data to the SERVER and which will be further saved to the MySql database and Web2Py application will display the updated data to the CLIENT.
 So the scenarios are:
1.  SERVER can act like a client when CLIENT can request some data from N/W Panel (here N/W Panel acts as Server) using Web2Py application.
2.  N/W Panel can act like a client when it gets some updated data from different devices and needs to save to the MySql database which is running on SERVER(here SERVER acts as Server).

Now My question is how to achieve it using web services as it is a bi-directional communication between SERVER and N/W Panel AND how to integrate with Web2Py application?
Web services can be SOAP OR REST.

Regards,
Piks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a server can act as a client. This is not a problem, and the answer to "how to do it" is basically just "Do it!".  :-)

You use some client library, which may be anything from the standard library supports for http, or some special SOAP or REST library if that's what you want to use, and you make the requests from the server. It's really as easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed this manual page? It contains client side code for some examples ...

http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10#Remote-procedure-calls